# Why the word remnants not reminants?

Tags: word-usage, etymology

I understand the word "remain", but I cannot understand why it's remina-nts, it looks like someone incorrectly write down the word re-main into re-mina, so hilarious.... Not to be offend because I know nothing about it, but I'm very willing to understand the story behind the scene!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Remnant” didn’t develop from “remain.” They both developed from an older Latin word through French. You’re right though: “remainant” would be the logical noun, but English has a rich history that doesn’t always follow logical rules.

Comment: Indeed, the best rule is no rule. Flexibility follows :)

Answer (score 1):

To add more detail to Josh B.'s answer:

> [**remain**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/remain) (v): early 15c., from Anglo-French *remayn-*, Old French *remain*-, stressed stem of *remanoir* "to stay, dwell, remain; be left; hold out," from Latin *remanere* "to remain, to stay behind; be left behind; endure, abide, last" (source also of Old Spanish *remaner*, Italian *rimanere*), from re- "back" (see re-) + *manere* "to stay, remain" (from PIE root *men- (3) "to remain"). Related: Remained; remaining.
>
> **[remnant](https://www.etymonline.com/word/remnant#etymonline_v_10409)** (n.): late 14c., contraction of *remenant* (c. 1300), from Old French *remanant* "rest, remainder, surplus," noun use of present participle of *remanoir* "to remain" (see remain (v.)).

It seems that your objection is accurate -- the original word was indeed *remenant*, but 600 years or so ago it was contracted to the modern *remnant* for reasons no one now knows.  These things happen.